# "Whine" vs. "Grumble"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between ***whine*** and ***grumble*** as verbs meaning *complain*? 
Does it only have to do with the pitch of your voice or are there more differences?

Comment: Pragmatically, someone who grumbles is still likely to productively contribute to dealing with whatever is causing the distress, while the whiner will simply whine.  I'll take the grumbler over the whiner any day.

Comment: A whine has a carrier frequency, a hum. A grumble is just a _sotto voce_ complaint, unintelligible except for its existence. Grumbling is strictly a human vocal sound, while whines can be produced by many different kinds of physical or mechanical phenomena; but both are sounds. From these actual sounds come the metaphoric senses in the discussion, which reflect the pragmatics of their use.

Comment: If I'm alone and no one else can hear me, I might well grumble, for example about the slowness of my computer, but I don't think it would make sense to whine.

Answer (score 2):

The intended effects of the actions differ.  Whining is generally an attempt to overtly express one's distress.  Grumbling, however tends to be more discrete.  Pitch, as you said comes into play as well as volume.

Students might whine to a teacher to bring attention to their distress about homework.

Employees might grumbe about a bad boss to share in their distain while not bringing attention to it.  In this case attention is bad.

Comment: Doesn't it also have to do with what you complain about? That is, you whine about unimportant things when no one thinks you really need to say those things, like when you "whine about the weather", but you grumble about something when you feel you have been treated unfairly or you think you actually have the right to do it like when you "grumble about your boss's unusual strictness" ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does it only have to do with the pitch of your voice or are there more differences?

### Yes.  It only has to do with the pitch.

That is the only thing that separates the two verbs.  Although grumbling is usually a bit more passive aggressive, if not aggressive.  Fights could be started over someone grumbling.

Fights could also be started from `whining`, but anyone that started such a fight would have had to be annoyed to the point of violence.

Comment: Whining suggests overt expression of discontent, while grumbling is done in private.